# having trouble reading the status of a checkbox in meteor

Tags: javascript, html, forms, checkbox, meteor

Meteor newbie.

I am trying to experiment with a really simple form in meteor. Basically, I have a textbox, a submit button and a checkbox.

When I click the submit button, I want to see the following returned into my browser console.

- Form submitted
- submit
- what ever is typed into the checkbox
- and the status of the checkbox (I have 2 methods currently)

So far, all is ok, with the exception of the checkbox status. i have tried 2 methods, 1 always returns on and the other returns undefined.

I have been looking at this for days, and just cannot get it. If anyone can help, that would be really appreciated. I think I am close, just need a proper way to read the checkbox.

Here is the code I have sofa...

html file
<---

```
<template name="InputForm">
    <form>
      <input type="text" name="inputa">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxstatus" id="checkboxa" checked="{{isChecked}}"/> Click Me
    </form>
</template>
```

--->

JS file
<---

```
 Template.InputForm.events({
    'submit form': function(){
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log("Form submitted");
      console.log(event.type);
      var inputAVar = event.target.inputa.value;
      console.log(inputAVar);
      var checkboxAVar1 = event.target.checkboxstatus.value;
      console.log(checkboxAVar1);
      var checkboxAVar2 = Session.get("isChecked");
      console.log(checkboxAVar2);
      //console.log(isChecked);

  }
  });
```

--->

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I don't think I will be able to sleep until I can read the status of this checkbox.

Steve

Comment: Try using `checkboxstatus.checked` instead of `checkboxstatus.value`. See the [MDN docs on JavaScript's HTMLInputElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement).

Comment: THankyou sbking, your suggestions worked a treat! Thankyou, now I can sleep tonight!!! PS, thanks for the link, very useful indeed! Bookmarked! Steve